# Nothing gives an output

Tags: java, android, sqlite

This is a code to store data of a particular column in database to an array list.

```
ArrayList<String> mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor mCursor = null;
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        while(!mCursor.isAfterLast()) {
             mArrayList.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.SOURCE_NODE_ID)));
             mCursor.moveToNext();
        }

for(String d1:mArrayList) {
                    System.out.println(d1);}
```

but after running the program nothing gives in the output.

what is wrong in this program ?

thanks.

Comment: i believe your app is crashing, rite?

Comment: are your code are completed ? if no, please paste the full code block, if yes, there will throw a `NullPointerException` in line ` mCursor.moveToFirst();`

Comment: How you are able run the program it will throw nullpointer exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will through null pointer exception:

```
Cursor mCursor = null;
mCursor.moveToFirst();
```

Comment: I am new please give me direction to initialize the cursor .

Comment: yes sure ... for what I am here but some people are more inserted in pulling leg more than giving answer and misdirect your aim also......  Can I know what type the data you are looking for? is it your internal DB is there or you want data from some other application...

Comment: so make the qurey that will return you the cursor .. like ex  http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `System.out.println` in android, instead, use `Log.d`:

```
for(String d1:mArrayList) {
    Log.d("myApp", d1);
}
```

As pointed out by others, `mCursor` is null, but I assume this is only what you wrote here and not your actual code, as such code will result in **NullPointerException** and application crash.

Comment: what if want want output in console and run the program as java application ?

Comment: If you run it on Android, there is no console.  If you run it on a computer, then you can use `System.out.println`.

Answer (score 0):

That should give a NullPointerException since you're trying to work with a null object.